# What is naming convention for hub.docker.com builds

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So I have an application called *SongKong*, I wanted to build a Docker image for it. Within hub.docker.com you can link to a repository containing Dockerfile and build from it, I do not want to call this repos *songkong* because I already have a *songkong* repo for the actual application code. So I called the repo *songkongdocker* but now my hub.docker.com repo is called *songkongdocker*, it would seem that hub.docker repos are usually named after the application so ideally should just be *songkong*

So, what is the correct way to name and can my Bitbucket code repository have a different name then the hub.docker.com repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change build/repo name when you are creating an Automated build on hub.docker.com. Bitbucket/Github repo name is used as a default name, but you can still edit it.

Comment: Great, thats works, the UI is confusing I though I was changing the name of the bitbucker repository but it did work as you said. So i keep my bitbucket repo as songkongdocker but now have my docker file automatedbuild as songkong.